# JAVA - How to code Node neighbours in a Grid?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and as a school task I need to implement BFS, DFS and A* search algorithms in Java to search for a given Goal from a given start position in a Grid of given size, 4x4, 8x8, etc.

To begin with I don't know how to code the neighbors of all the nodes. For example in a 8x8 grid tile 1 has 2 and 9 as neighbors and Tile 12 has 4, 11, 13 and 20 as its neighbours but i'm struggling to code that. I need the neighbours part so that i can move from start position to other parts of gird legally by moving horizontally or vertically through the neighbours.

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 
57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
```

my node class is:

```
class Node {
   int value;
   LinkedList<Node> neighbors;
   bool expanded;
}
```

Let's say i'm given a 8x8 grid right, So if i start the program with a grid of size 8x8 right :

1 - my main method will create an arrayList of nodes for example node

```
ArrayList<Node> test = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

and then using a for loop assign value to all the nodes in arrayList from 1 to 64 (if the grid size was 8x8).

BUT somehow i need to add the neighbors of each node, if anyone can give me some details i would really appreciate it.

Comment: @ke3pup: edited your question, you could do an effort to better format your question and verify the working, it was difficult to see what you were talking about since that you said *"Tile 12 has 141,13,20 as its neighbors"* [sic] instead of "4, 11, 13, 20". I also added that you were talking about a 8x8 square (not a 4x4) and put up a square showing the tile numbers so that people can better understand your question.

Comment: oops, just noticed... You Node class should start with an uppercase 'N' (because that's the Java convention).

Comment: thanks for the correction again WizardOfOdds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your `Node`s are laid out in `M` rows and `N` columns. For simplicity, let `nodes[r][c]` be the reference to `Node` at row `r` and column `c` (zero-based indexing), currently with empty `List<Node> neighbors` that we want to build.

Here's one way to build them:

```
for (int r = 0; r < M; r++) {
  for (int c = 0; c < N; c++) {
    Node n = nodes[r][c];
    List<Node> neighbors = n.neighbors;
    if (r > 0) {     // has north
      neighbors.add(nodes[r-1][c]);
    }
    if (r < M - 1) { // has south
      neighbors.add(nodes[r+1][c]);
    }
    if (c > 0) {     // has west
      neighbors.add(nodes[r][c-1]);
    }
    if (c < N - 1) { // has east
      neighbors.add(nodes[r][c+1]);
    }
  }
}
```

---

> my `main` method will create an `ArrayList<Node>`

It's so much easier to handle a grid in a 2-dimensional data structure, be it an array-of-array or list-of-list. If you insist on having a 1-D list, then instead of `nodes[r][c]`, you call `nodeAt(r, c)` helper function:

```
Node nodeAt(int r, int c) {
   return nodesList.get(r * N + c);
}
```

This is a standard transformation from 2-D indexing to 1-D (assuming [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)).